# Mapping locations between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

This a relatively simple problem, though it is proving cumbersome for me to nail down.

I have 2 arrays filled with pages. One with pages and, one with pages and ads.

```
pages = ['page1','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6','page7','page8','page9']

pages_w_ads = ['page1','page2', 'ad','page3','page4','ad','page5','page6','ad','page7','page8','ad','page9']
```

I need to get the array location of a page in the `pages_w_ads` array based on the a location in the pages array, excluding ads. Ads are show every 2 items in the `pages_w_ads` array.

Example : `pages[8] === pages_w_ads[11];`

How might I find the location of my page in the pages_w_ads array?

Here is a basic js fiddle of my current implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/myyellowshoe/qsL6uyw2/2/

Thanks for any wisdom.

Comment: pages_w_ads.indexOf(strPage)

Comment: Since you tagged your post with `math` try the following formula `pages[i] = i + Math.floor(i/3);`

Comment: @dandavis In my case I'm dealing with objects so won't work just doing a straight indexof.

Comment: @PM77-1, I used something like this, but this still ended up landing me on an ad page in the pages_w_ads. I could have implemented it improperly though.

Comment: Give me a sample where my formula does not work and I gladly adjust it.

Comment: if the pages are really the same, indexOf will still work with objects...

Comment: @PM77-1 added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qsL6uyw2/

Comment: @dandavis, in my situation the object properties might vary. So would like to find a purely location based solution.

Comment: It comes up **empty** for me. Can you see the content using your link?

Comment: @Justin -- Post your actual data, not something *similar* - or all we can give is partial answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Example: `pages[8] === pages_w_ads[11];`

That's not true. The first element of an array is in the key `0`, so

```js
pages[8] === pages_w_ads[12]; // "page9"
```

Therefore, the equality is

```js
pages[i] === pages_w_ads[Math.floor(i*1.5)]; // "page" + (i+1)
```

Comment: I tested this on yesterday and this works great. I updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/myyellowshoe/qsL6uyw2/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to this: one is dealing with the ad-pages and the other is the fact that the pages aren't actually 0-based as Javascript arrays actually are.

```
var getPage = function (n) {
  return pages_w_ads[(n - 1) + Math.floor(n/3)];
}
console.log(getPage(1)); //Returns page1
console.log(getPage(2)); //Returns page2
console.log(getPage(3)); //Returns page3
console.log(getPage(4)); //Returns page4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use indexOf() array function with id what you are sending to function with common "page" name

```
Ex: return pages_w_ads[pages_w_ads.indexOf("page"+pid)]
```